# generic function call in typescript throws error

Tags: typescript

I have certain code that looks like this

```
interface KnockoutObservableArrayStatic {
    fn: KnockoutObservableArrayFunctions<any>;
    <T>(value?: T[]): KnockoutObservableArray<T>;
}
declare var ko: KnockoutObservableArrayStatic;
```

I want to create a empty observable array with type *TElement*, which should be something like this

```
var elementArray: TElement[] = null;
var observableArray = ko(elementArray);
```

But compiler gives me error

> Cannot convert 'KnockoutObservableArray' to 'KnockoutObservableArray':
>       Call signatures of types 'KnockoutObservableArray' and 'KnockoutObservableArray' are incompatible

How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing all of the code, but this sounds like a compiler bug (you shouldn't see "Cannot convert T to T" errors ever, basically). If you could [post an issue](https://typescript.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create) with a self-contained example I can verify if the code compiles with the latest TypeScript compiler. There have been several bugs around generic compatibility with the Knockout type structure like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when compiled solution in VS2013.

I deleted this two lines from MyProject.csproj file

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

and errors went out.